# Их работы / Их видели

Tags: грамматика, местоимения

Чем отличаются *их* в этих оборотах?

Comment: Обращайте внимание на метки, которые ставите.

Answer (score 2):

***Их работы.***  *Их* - местоимение **притяжательное**: *работы (чьи?) их*.

1. Является определением.
2. Не изменяется по падежам.

К притяжательным относятся местоимения *мой, твой, наш, ваш, свой.* Притяжательными являются также местоимения 3 лица *его, её, их*, которые отвечают на вопрос *чей?*, не изменяются по падежам и не согласуются с определяемыми существительными по числу и роду: *его работа, её работы, их работа* и пр.

***Видели их.***   *Их* - **личное** местоимение 3 лица: *видели (кого?) их*.

1. Личное местоимение *их* здесь является дополнением.
2. При изменениии личного местоимения по падежам может появиться начальная Н - *о них*.